# How did Drogon know that Dany was in trouble?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In S05E09 "[**The Dance of Dragons**](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/The_Dance_of_Dragons)", [Daenerys Targaryen](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Daenerys_Targaryen) and her advisors find themselves

> surrounded in the arena by The Sons of the Harpy, vastly out-numbered.

The situation looks pretty grim, when all of a sudden

> a dragon's roar is heard, and her missing dragon [Drogon](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Drogon) shows up to defend Dany & her friends. After he is wounded by the Sons, Dany climbs onto his back and flies off.

This scene played out differently in the books. In the book, the dragon

> was drawn to the arena early on, attracted to the sounds of battle & the smell of blood. Once he landed, he was pretty much out of control - breathing fire at everyone and everything, including Dany herself. She ultimately had to use a whip on him, and flew away with him as much to save everyone else as anything.

**Within the context of the show, how did Drogon know that Dany needed him, and how did he know who to attack?**

I haven't seen all of Season 5 yet so I'm assuming maybe I missed something.

Comment: Season 5 was a giant enormous plothole in itself. I don't think there's an explanation to this truly.

Comment: @yondaime008 agreed, with every season it's getting worse and worse. But at least D&D are explaining major events in their inside the episodes.

Comment: @yondaime008: was it, or is it just diverging from the books? (I ask as a non-book-reader, and wonder if it’s easier for me to accept the TV plots because I haven’t read them.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite well to be short, a lot of side arcs that could explain certain events were skipped, a lot of characters didnt' even make it to the show and were replaced by others which made a new confusion as these characters were put in situations they were not supposed to be in, Sansa Stark is an example of that as she never was supposed to marry Ramsay or even come near Winterfell. these differences are a bit tough to manage and I believe generated a lot of plotholes (i am not a show watcher btw)

Comment: @yondaime008: “a lot of characters didnt' even make it to the show and were replaced by others which made a new confusion as these characters were put in situations they were not supposed to be in” — well, I think that’s only confusing if you’re watching the show and expecting it to be a literal adaptation of the books. In the show, Sansa marrying Ramsay seems to make sense — the Boltons are trying to legitimise their claim to the North; and Littlefinger is trying to play all sides at once.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I agree, but if the show is going to rely on the plot of the books, those characters have other stuff destined to do, and putting them in different situations kinda makes it hard to resolve later on. The issue is that there are quite a few important arcs that were ignored, such as lord Griffs arc and Quentyn Martells, i have no idea how will this be tackled in the future without causing  problems.

Comment: @yondaime008: is there anything in particular? (I’m cool with spoilers at this point.) I think as long as the TV show makes sense on its own terms, it doesn’t really matter if it’s increasingly divergent from the books. TV shows aren’t novels.

Comment: Well I don't wana spoil people reading this conversation so if u reading this there may be some spoilers ahead, that being said, the book ADWD explains how another targaryen is alive and ready to claim the throne in a surprising turn of events, and Tyrion met him on his journey in Essos. The kid is Young Griff that has been protected by the Lord Griffin who was a lord at the service of the targaryens and the whole Golden Company was made up with deserting westeros knights and warriors to serve him when he grows up to claim. So, i dunno how are they gonna cover this now.

Comment: @yondaime008 I have a feeling they're just going to skip the Griff arc altogether. For all we know, GRRM will suddenly kill him off in the next book, and the producers know what's coming.

Comment: @Omegacron maybe, and maybe he'll turn out to be the valonqar, after all, the description fit him very very well. Also, the fact that Varys knows about him, gives Varys another dimension, that of an elusive man, even at the service of the targaryens, i mean why didn't he tell Daenerys about him ?

Comment: @yondaime008 well that's what I mean - in the show there hasn't even been the slightest hint that he exists. Unless his sudden appearance and identity are a huge twist of Season 6, I don't see it happening at all there. Which could very well mean that it falls flat in the books as well. The majority of hype around that character is fan speculation that has yet to be confirmed by GRRM.

Comment: @Omegacron on that I'll have to agree, it is true that I am only feeling betrayed by the show, because i long wanted to see certain events take place in the screen. Nevertheless, things could've been done much better in my honest opinion than it was delivered in season 5 sadly.

Comment: @yondamie0008 - If you're not a show watcher, how can you know if the show has plot holes or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

David Benioff has confirmed that

> Dany and Drogon share deep connection. And the event in the fighting pit is evidence that Drogon has ability to sense when Dany is in peril.

for more details watch 
[Game of Thrones Season 5: Inside the Episode #9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NfLScJVXBHQ) from 6:44

Comment: "My dragons made no such promise. And you have threatened their mother."

Comment: Also interesting is the second paragraph of Dragonriders of [this wiki page](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dragon#Dragonriders) which implies that in the past there were also evidence of a dragon sensing something happening to the one bonded to it.

Answer (score 6):

I was going to try answering this even before I saw that you were familiar with the scene in the books. But basically, a few established facts to consider:

**SPOILERS AHEAD:**

- Drogon has been shown (in earlier episodes) to frequent the area before this scene, notably in areas around Dany (like the pyramid/ziggurat she lives in on that one night on her balcony)
- Dragons have been shown previously to have strong senses, especially that of smell and hearing based on their repeated scenes of flaring nostrils and sniffing sounds, and their ability to hear Dany even when she whispers subtly to them or others, and their ability to hear others approach before the human characters do
- The arena was VERY noisy, with plenty of sounds of screams and yells of combat, long before the Dragon showed up. Along with the other points above, I think it's safe to follow the show's logic and it is very much aligned with that same reasoning used in the book.
- As for who the dragon attacked, note how few of her allies are among those people on the sand. Literally everyone in an open area aside from her merry little group was an enemy, and it is shown that the dragon is attacking at random first, then focuses on those attacking it afterward (which were Dany's enemies). And, to help out even more, the dragons haven't just been shown to care for and want to protect Dany, but they've been shown as smart enough to recognize threats to her as well.

Comment: Ziggurat! Haven't read that word in a while :D Perfect usage though....

Comment: This is the correct book-based answer. Drogon was simply attracted to the noise and the smell of the fighters' blood.

Answer (score 1):

Dragons are smart beasts who can sense the distress of their riders. A dragon and its rider share a very deep and mysterious bond which is formed at times when either party is either in the crib or egg.

They can sense their rider's likes and dislikes, their enemies, their friends and their families.

> Even after Ser Otto had returned to Oldtown, a “queen’s party” still
>   existed at court; a group of powerful lords friendly to Queen Alicent
>   and supportive of the rights of her sons. Against them was pitted the
>   “party of the princess.” King Viserys loved both his wife and daughter
>   and hated conflict and contention. He strove all his days to keep the
>   peace between his women and to please both with gifts and gold and
>   honors. So long as he lived and ruled and kept the balance, the feasts
>   and tourneys continued as before, and peace prevailed throughout the
>   realm … though there were some, sharp-eyed, **who observed the dragons
>   of one party snapping and spitting flame at the dragons of the other
>   party whenever they chanced to pass near each other.**
> <sub>The Rogue Prince</sub>

and

> **We shall not pretend to any understanding of the bond between dragon and dragonrider; wiser heads have pondered that mystery for
>   centuries.** We do know, however, that dragons are not horses, to be
>   ridden by any man who throws a saddle on their back. Syrax was the
>   queen’s dragon. She had never known another rider. **Though Prince
>   Joffrey was known to her by sight and scent, a familiar presence whose
>   fumbling at her chains excited no alarm**, the great yellow she-dragon
>   wanted no part of him astride her.
> <sub>The Princess and the Queen</sub>

This is not the first time a Dragon has shown some mysterious knowledge of their rider's distress. Queen Helaena's dragon snapped her chains when she jumped from the Red Keep even though the dragon was miles away at the Dragonpit.

> The rumor of Queen Helaena’s “murder” was soon on the lips of half
>   King’s Landing. That it was so quickly believed shows how utterly the
>   city had turned against their once-beloved queen. Rhaenyra was hated;
>   Helaena had been loved. Nor had the common folk of the city forgotten
>   the cruel murder of Prince Jaehaerys by Blood and Cheese. Helaena’s
>   end had been mercifully swift; one of the spikes took her through the
>   throat and she died without a sound. **At the moment of her death,
>   across the city atop the Hill of Rhaenys, her dragon Dreamfyre rose
>   suddenly with a roar that shook the Dragonpit, snapping two of the
>   chains that bound her.** When Queen Alicent was informed of her
>   daughter’s passing, she rent her garments and pronounced a dire curse
>   upon her rival. That night King’s Landing rose in bloody riot.
> <sub>The Princess and the Queen</sub>

However in the episode that you describe, Daenerys was in no immediate danger. In the opening games of Daznak's reopening, Drogon was attracted by blood and fire as Dragons are wont to do. He killed the boar and Barsena and ate them both. Barristan Selmy thinks it was the blood and war that attracted Drogon to the pit:

> They will come, Ser Barristan might have said. The noise will bring
>   them, the shouts and screams, the scent of blood. That will draw them
>   to the battlefield, just as the roar from Daznak's Pit drew Drogon to
>   the scarlet sands.
> <sub>ADWD: The Queen's Hand</sub>

However, we must note that Drogon has sensed Dany's distress before at the House of the Undying and saved her life.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main reason Dragon sensed the dense cheering crowd and it got the smell of blood and that attracted it in slaughter pit, it was near by to the fighting area.

Answer (score 0):

With almost every Stark having a some level of psychic/warg connection to their direwolves, is it so outlandish to think that someone descended from a family with a history bound to those of dragons, who has an ability to withstand inferno fires (which would seem a bit more implausible), might have some sort of mental bond with her dragons?

Especially where you can always pull out a cop-out answer of "magic." (Stannis kills his brother, people coming back from the dead, etc).